# My Do-While loop breaks when I hit my keyboard input for the second time

Tags: java

I am only a few weeks in on coding so I'm really new. This is a simple program that assists the user in customizing a new car. The program uses different methods for each of the respective menus. each method that isn't main asks the user which of 2 custom car options they would like then the method sends back a cost to the main. Each method that isn't main uses the same format as the method `engineCost`. I can't figure out why my keyboard input only functions during the first iteration of my do while loop. This is the error I am prompted with on eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

I did some looking on stack overflow and I don't think I'm knowledgeable enough to search for the answer properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch5HW {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double baseCar = 14000;
        double addCost = 0;
        double ttlCost = 0;
        int userOpt;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Basic Car includes: Silver color, 4 cilinder engine, Cooper Tires; cost: $14,000");
        System.out.println("");
        //this do-while loops until the user enters 4 to exit 
        do{
            System.out.println("Build Car Quote");
            System.out.println("1. Engine");
            System.out.println("2. Color");
            System.out.println("3. Tires");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");

            System.out.print("Enter Option: ");
            userOpt = 0;
            // this keyboard input only works on the first iteration of the loop
            userOpt = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println(userOpt);
            //nested switch to determine userOpt
            switch (userOpt)
            {
            case 1:
                // calls the engineCost method
                addCost = engineCost();
                //adds the value received to a total value
                ttlCost += addCost;
            break;

            case 2:
                //calls the colorOpt method
                addCost = colorOpt();
                //adds the value received to a total value
                ttlCost += addCost;
            break;

            case 3:
                //calls the tireOpt method
                addCost = tireOpt();
                //adds the value received to a total value
                ttlCost += addCost;
            break;
            }
            //System.out.print(addCost + baseCar);
            keyboard.close();
        } 
        while (userOpt !=4);
        //once loop has finished the total of additional purchases is added to the base car price 
        System.out.print("Total cost: " + (ttlCost + baseCar));
    }
    // this method has options for the engine
    static double engineCost()
    {
        double engineCost = 0;
        double addCost =0;
        int engineOpt;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Engine Options: ");
        System.out.println("1. 8 cylinder: $5000.00");
        System.out.println("2. 6 cylinder: $3500.00");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter Option: ");
        engineOpt = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch (engineOpt)
        {
        case 1:
            engineCost = 5000.00;
            addCost += engineCost;
        break;
        case 2:
            engineCost = 3500.00;
            addCost += engineCost;
        break;  
        case 3:
            engineCost = 0;
            addCost += engineCost;
        }
        keyboard.close();
        return addCost; 
    }
}
```

Comment: close keyboard after while.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the line: `keyboard.close();` within your loop. This closes the `Scanner` after your first iteration. After this you try to call `nextInt()` which (from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int))) will throw:

> `IllegalStateException` - if this scanner is closed

You should only close a resource *after* you are completely done with it.

That being said do not close `System.in`. The general rule is that if you did not open it, your should not close it.